# How to position multiple buttons on the same line separately in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create two buttons in same line separately.I used flex=2 but it's not working.How can i fix that?

```
<View style={{ flex: 2,flexDirection: "row" ,marginLeft:20}}>
    <BtnDft h={40} w={100} name={ "Update"} />
    <BtnDft h={40} w={100} name={ "Log out"} />
</View>
```

Comment: when you say it's not working what do you mean?

Comment: I mean flex is not working for separate that buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `flex: 2`

```
{ flexDirection: "row" ,marginLeft: 20, justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }
```

change the position of the buttons using `justifyContent`, Available options are `flex-start`, `center`, `flex-end`, `space-around`, `space-between` and `space-evenly`.